# ReactJS best practices. I should make all my components with arrow function? And the non-component functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Should I make all my components with arrow functions?

This:

```
const Header = () => {
 return (
  <>Header...</>
 )
}
```

Or this?

```
function Header() {
 return (
  <>Header...</>
 )
}
```

**And with non-component functions?**

This:

```
const doubleNumber = ({number}) => {
 return number *2
}
```

Or this?

```
function Header({number}) {
 return number *2
}
```

I think that the arrow function is prettier to read.

There is a downside or a advantage to use it?

Comment: It doesn't matter much. Either function declaration and function expression works well. It's upto you what you prefer to write which pattern you are most comfortable with. The main difference between these two patterns is that.  Arrow function have lexical this.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions/
No need to avoid arrow functions.. It's the future :D

Comment: I don't think there is much difference.But arrow functions have been introduced as part of ES6 and they are much cleaner.Also,if you see the definition of lot of keywords [built in ],they will have definition as arrow fucntions.So knowing arrow function is good.Also,we don't need to use function keyword and return as you would already be aware .